# Is it possible to set a Calendar c equal Calendar c2?

Tags: java

I have:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,23);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,22);

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

c2 = c ; //
```

is this last statement correct if I want to set Calendar c2 equal to Calendar c ?

Comment: I hope its correct..!

Comment: Why not write a little test program to compare the results for yourself?

Comment: This statement will assign a reference to `c` to the variable `c2`. (`c == c2` will be `true`).

Comment: Why set `c2` to `Calendar.getInstance()` at all if you're going to overwrite the value?

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm just creating an instance of it.. just as if it was Calendar c = new Calendar(); so I thought Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance() would create an instance of it

Comment: do they need to be identical, or just hold the same date. you could just call c2.setTime(c.getTime)

Comment: @WilliamFox: Yes, but then you're ignoring that instance completely.

Answer (score 14):

Although `c2 = c` would appear to work, that's not what you want: both variables will be pointing to the same calendar instance. As the result of this assignment, any changes made to `c` will be in `c2` as well, and vice versa.

You can use `clone()` method to make a copy of the `Calendar` object, like this:

```
Calendar c= (Calendar)c2.clone();
```

Comment: This is what I want! Thank you so much. EDIT: Your answer is awesome!

Comment: I just saw this behavior in my code ! Could not believe my eyes and had to search for confirmation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
c2 = c ;
```

will copy the value of `c` into `c2`. The value of `c` is *not* a `Calendar` object - it's a reference. After this statement, the two variables have the same value - two references to the same object. Any changes to the `Calendar` object can be observed via either variable.

It's like giving two different people pieces of paper giving your home address - if one person uses the address to get to your house and paints the front door green, then the other person will see that too.

Note that this isn't `Calendar`-specific - this is the behaviour of assignment for *all* classes in Java.

(It's very important to distinguish between variables, references and objects, basically. In normal discussion the three are often used incorrectly for the sake of brevity, but you need to be able to tell the difference when you need to.)

Note that this code:

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2 = c;
```

is creating a new `Calendar` instance pointlessly. It would be written more sensibly as:

```
Calendar c2 = c;
```

That code will have the same visible effect, but without calling `Calendar.getInstance()` and then throwing away the newly-created object.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet! Awesome answer too! I now understand more about Java classes!

Answer (score 2):

c2 = c means you will have 2 fields pointing to the same instance. if you modify c you will ALSO modify c2

c2 = c.clone() clones the instance and returns you another instance. if you modify c you will NOT modify c2

Answer (score 0):

Calendar class has got a method `compareTo`.  have a look on that

[CompareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29)

Comment: yes but I don't want to compare them, I want to set one calendar equal to another one

Answer (score -1):

You dont even need `c2 = Calendar.getInstance()`, just assign directly 'c2 = c'.